# What does the "resources" directive do in Puppet?

Tags: resources, puppet

I recently came across the following code while learning puppet. I need to understand  what the "resources" directive does in puppet code. Could anyone point me to any documentation online?

```
resources { 'firewall':
purge => true,
}
```

Does this directive perform actions/commands on an entire set of resources of a specific type?

Need pointers to any documentation that would answer my query.

Answer (score 0):

The `resources` resource is documented at https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/types/resources.html. `resources` is usually used for purging resources of a certain type which aren't managed by Puppet. In your example, `firewall` resources are purged, so only firewall rules managed by Puppet are allowed.